# Return statement will never be executed warning

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-warnings

I've recently come across with double `return` statement (one of them was added by mistake) in our project and wondering why `compiler` doesn't show a warning for that?!

Ok, I added `-Wunreachable-code` to other warning flags, but still no luck.

Got warning - with a code to execute after `return` statement:

[image]

Didn't get warning but still second `return` statement will never be executed.
[image]

Even if I add something like this, still no warning

[image]

Is there extra warning flag for that, or compiler isn't smart enough?

Comment: because your method return exit before execute that codes

Comment: for both examples, so what?

Comment: for both examples your method never execute after return

Comment: mm.. This is my question actually, in first case I got warning in second - NOT... what's point in downvoting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good catch!

`-Wunreachable-code` does not report a warning and there is no other warning flag which would do.
Not even the Static Analyzer catches this mistake!

(Tested with XCode 6.1 GM 2)

Comment: but all warnings will disappear... I guess it is inappropriate for topicstarter.

Comment: Why should all warnings disappear? `-Wunreachable-code` enables **more** warnings, although it won't catch the one mentioned by the topic starter.

Comment: `-Wunreachable-code` will enable these warnings, not disable them.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code in pragma flags that will suppress that warning between the push and pop

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunreachable-code"
//Your code goes here
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `-Wno-unreachable-code` for your file in Build Phases.

Answer (score -4):

Try this...

```
-(NSString*) makeSomeStringForMe {

    NSString *someString = @"some string";

    return someString;

}
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to add an explanation of what this code does, and how it addresses the question?